# Weird compile error dealing with Winnt.h

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi

When trying to compile a file that include winnt.h via windows.h, I get the following error:

```
MyGl.cpp
..\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h(964) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
..\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winnt.h(964) : error C2059: syntax error : '&'
```

They point to the following lines in Winnt.h

```
extern "C++" // templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
template <typename T, size_t N>
char (*RtlpNumberOf( UNALIGNED T (&)[N] ))[N];

#define RTL_NUMBER_OF_V2(A) (sizeof(*RtlpNumberOf(A)))
```

Any ideas for what's going on?

My compiler:

```
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Comment: What version of what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this.  The first is to simply include `windows.h` at the top of all your files. Then include `winnt.h` only if you need it. However, I find this a bit too much - I don't see the need of including all this goo in every single file.

What I do is this at the very top (first thing) in my C/C++ header files.

```
#ifndef __wtypes_h__
#include <wtypes.h>
#endif

#ifndef __WINDEF_
#include <windef.h>
#endif
```

This will get you you the data types, defines, and fundamental Windows API's.   You may also need to add the following:

```
#ifndef _WINUSER_
#include <winuser.h>
#endif

#ifndef __RPC_H__
#include <rpc.h>
#endif
```

WinNT is a bit of a special animal - don't include it if including the above files works for you.  If you do need it, include it after `wtypes.h` and `windef.h'

If this doesn't work, then check your include paths and predefined macros to see if those might be breaking your build.

Regards, Foredecker

Comment: You just saved another batch of hours of my work. Thank you sir.

Comment: the odd part about this answer is that the question states `winnt.h` is being included via `windows.h`, so in what condition would you need to include `winnt.h`, and how does such an answer even address the issue given that it is being included via `windows.h`? it seems like your all encompassing statement: **check your include paths and predefined macros to see if those might be breaking your build** is the only reason this addressed (dare I say, solved) the underline issue..

Comment: This answer is very misleading. `wtypes.h` includes `rpc.h`, which in turn includes `windows.h`. So all this code just ends up being the same as a simple `#include <Windows.h>`.