# error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ContextRecord'

Tags: c++, header, xaudio2

i have a header file which contained all of the class' functions including code so the class didn't have a cpp file. everything worked. I added the cpp file and moved the function code over to that and now i get this error when compiling. the header that im getting the error in ((x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(6361)) isnt even included by the file that im changing. does anyone know what the reason for this might be? i can provide code i just don't know what would be helpful.

the cpp file:

```
#include "Fisherman.h"

void Fisherman::Initialise(){

memset((void*)&mListener, 0, sizeof(X3DAUDIO_LISTENER));
memset((void*)&mEmitter, 0, sizeof(X3DAUDIO_EMITTER));
memset((void*)&mDSPSettings, 0, sizeof(X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS));

XAUDIO2_VOICE_DETAILS details;
mCastSplash->GetSourceVoice()->GetVoiceDetails(&details);       
mEmitter.ChannelCount = details.InputChannels; 
mEmitter.CurveDistanceScaler = 1.0f;
X3DAUDIO_VECTOR emitterPos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}; 
mEmitter.Position = emitterPos;
X3DAUDIO_VECTOR emitterVel = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }; 
mEmitter.Velocity = emitterVel;

mDSPSettings.SrcChannelCount = mEmitter.ChannelCount; 
mDSPSettings.DstChannelCount = mXACore->GetChannelCount();

FLOAT32 * matrix = new FLOAT32[mDSPSettings.SrcChannelCount * mDSPSettings.DstChannelCount];

mDSPSettings.pMatrixCoefficients = matrix;

X3DAUDIO_VECTOR front = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }; 
X3DAUDIO_VECTOR top = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f }; 
mListener.OrientFront = front;
mListener.OrientTop = top;
X3DAUDIO_VECTOR listenerVel = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
mListener.Velocity = listenerVel;
X3DAUDIO_VECTOR listenerPos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }; 
mListener.Position = listenerPos;
}

void Fisherman::Rotate (int MouseDeltaX){
X3DAUDIO_VECTOR input = mListener.OrientFront;
X3DAUDIO_VECTOR result;
float theta = -(X3DAUDIO_PI/1000)*MouseDeltaX;

float cs = cos(theta);
float sn = sin(theta);

if(cs < 0.00001) cs = 0.0f;

result.x = input.x * cs - input.z * sn;
result.z = input.x * sn + input.z * cs;
result.y = 0.0f;

mListener.OrientFront = result;

}

bool Fisherman::Cast(Fish* aFish){
mCast->Play(0);
mCastOut = true;
mFish = aFish;

X3DAUDIO_VECTOR seg_v = Multiply(mListener.OrientFront, 30);

X3DAUDIO_VECTOR pt_v = {mFish->GetX(), 0.0f, mFish->GetZ()};

float proj_v_length = Dot(pt_v, mListener.OrientFront);

X3DAUDIO_VECTOR proj_v = Multiply(mListener.OrientFront, proj_v_length);

X3DAUDIO_VECTOR dist_v = Subtract(pt_v, proj_v);

if(VectorLength(dist_v) < mFish->GetRadius()){
    mEmitter.Position = mFish->GetEmitter().Position;

    return true;
}else{

    mEmitter.Position = Multiply(mListener.OrientFront, 15);

    return false;
}

}

void Fisherman::ReelIn(Fish* aFish){

mFish = aFish;
mFish->MoveCloser(mReelSpeed);
mReelingIn = true;
}

void Fisherman::ReelOut(Fish* aFish){
mFish = aFish;
mFish->MoveFurther();
mReelingIn = false;
}

void Fisherman::SetReelSpeed(float deltaTime){ 
float reelSpeed = 1.0f - deltaTime;
if(reelSpeed < 0.0f){
    reelSpeed = 0.0f;
}

if(reelSpeed > 10){

    mReelSpeedList.push_back(reelSpeed);
    if(mReelSpeedList.size() > 3){
        mReelSpeedList.pop_front();
    }

    reelSpeed = 0.0f;
    std::list<float>::const_iterator iterator;
    for (iterator = mReelSpeedList.begin(); iterator != mReelSpeedList.end(); ++iterator){
            reelSpeed += *iterator;
    }


    mReelSpeed = reelSpeed/mReelSpeedList.size();
}else
    mReelSpeed = reelSpeed;
mReelClickTimer = 0.1 / mReelSpeed;

}

void Fisherman::PlayReelClick(){

if(!mReelClick[0]->IsPlaying()){
    mReelClick[0]->Play(0);
}else if(!mReelClick[1]->IsPlaying()){
    mReelClick[1]->Play(0);
}else if(!mReelClick[2]->IsPlaying()){
    mReelClick[2]->Play(0);
}else if(!mReelClick[3]->IsPlaying()){
    mReelClick[3]->Play(0);
}else if(!mReelClick[4]->IsPlaying()){
    mReelClick[4]->Play(0);
}else {
    return;
}
}

bool Fisherman::NothingPlaying(){ // check to see if any sounds are playing
if(mCast->IsPlaying())return false;
if(mCastSplash->IsPlaying())return false;
for(int i =0; i < REEL_CLICK_OBJECTS; i++){
    if(mReelClick[i]->IsPlaying()){
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
} 

void Fisherman::SetReelingIn(bool isReelingIn){
mReelingIn = isReelingIn;
}

void Fisherman::SetCastOut(bool hasCastOut){
    mCastOut = hasCastOut;
}

float Fisherman::GetReelClickTime(){
    return mReelClickTimer/CLICK_TIMER_MULTIPLIER;
}

bool Fisherman::IsReelingIn(){
    return mReelingIn;
}

float Fisherman::GetReelSpeed(){
    return mReelSpeed;
}

X3DAUDIO_LISTENER Fisherman::GetListener(){
    return mListener;
}

X3DAUDIO_EMITTER Fisherman::GetEmitter(){
    return mEmitter;
}

X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS Fisherman::GetSettings(){
    return mDSPSettings;
}

XASound* Fisherman::GetCastSound(){
    return mCast;
}

XASound* Fisherman::GetCastSplashSound(){
    return mCastSplash;
}

bool Fisherman::HasCastSplashed(){
    return mCastSplashBool;
}

void Fisherman::SetCastSplashed(bool splashed){
    mCastSplashBool = splashed;
}

bool Fisherman::IsCastOut(){
    return mCastOut;
}
```

the header:

```
#ifndef _FISHERMAN_H_
#define _FISHERMAN_H_

#include <X3DAudio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <list>

#include "VectorCalculations.h"
#include "Fish.h"
#include "XASound.hpp"
using AllanMilne::Audio::XASound;

const float CLICK_TIMER_MULTIPLIER = 2.5f;
const int REEL_CLICK_OBJECTS = 5;
class Fisherman{
public:

    Fisherman(XACore* aXACore, XASound *cast, XASound *castSplash, std::list<XASound*> reelClickList)
        : // a Fish Object pointer for the fisherman to interact with.
        mFish (NULL), mXACore (aXACore),
        //XASound objects with sounds for the fisherman
        mCast (cast), mCastSplash (castSplash)
    {
        mReelSpeedList.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < REEL_CLICK_OBJECTS; i++){
            mReelClick[i] = reelClickList.front();
            mReelClick[i]->SetVolume(2.0f);
            reelClickList.pop_front();
            mReelClickList.push_back(mReelClick[i]);

        }

        mCastSplash->SetVolume(7.0f);

        mXACore = aXACore;

        mCastSplashBool = false;
        mCastOut = false;
        mReelingIn = false;
        mCastDistance = 0.0f;
        Initialise();
    }

    ~Fisherman(){}

    void Initialise();

    void Rotate(int MouseDeltaX);

    bool Cast(Fish* aFish);

    void ReelIn(Fish* aFish);

    void ReelOut(Fish* aFish);

    void SetReelSpeed(float deltaTime);

    void PlayReelClick();

    bool NothingPlaying(); // check to see if any sounds are playing

    void SetFront(X3DAUDIO_VECTOR front);

    void SetReelingIn(bool isReelingIn);

    void SetCastOut(bool hasCastOut);

    float GetReelClickTime();

    bool IsReelingIn();

    float GetReelSpeed();

    X3DAUDIO_LISTENER GetListener();

    X3DAUDIO_EMITTER GetEmitter();

    X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS GetSettings();

    XASound* GetCastSound();

    XASound* GetCastSplashSound();

    bool HasCastSplashed();

    void SetCastSplashed(bool splashed);

    bool IsCastOut();


private:

    XACore *mXACore;

    XASound *mCast;
    XASound *mCastSplash;
    XASound *mReelClick[REEL_CLICK_OBJECTS];


    float mCastDistance; 
    float mReelClickTimer;
    float mReelSpeed;

    std::list<float> mReelSpeedList;
    std::list<XASound*> mReelClickList; 

    X3DAUDIO_LISTENER mListener; 
    X3DAUDIO_EMITTER mEmitter;
    X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS mDSPSettings;

    Fish *mFish;
    bool mCastOut;
    bool mCastSplashBool;
    bool mReelingIn;
};


#endif
```

including windows.h at the top of the header file solved this issue.

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful ;)

Comment: Do you have a semicolon at the end of your class declaration?

Comment: yes i do. that was my first thing i checked. I have other classes with cpp files so im not sure why this one is acting up.

Comment: You have an error in your code.

Comment: Wild guess: Try adding `#include <windows.h>` at the top.

Comment: well that got rid of the original error but has been replaced by this:1>FishyBonanza.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Fisherman::SetFront(struct _D3DVECTOR)" (?SetFront@Fisherman@@QAEXU_D3DVECTOR@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall FishyBonanza::ProcessGameFrame(float)" (?ProcessGameFrame@FishyBonanza@@UAEXM@Z)

Comment: @CalvinWylie: See my answer, where is `Fisherman::SetFront` in the cpp file?

Comment: ive fixed that. thanks for all your help the issue is resolved. i included windows.h at the top ofthe file. can anyone tell me why that worked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does the error also say `PCONTEXT undefined`?

Try adding `#include <Windows.h>` before `#include <X3DAudio.h>`.

In reply to comment about `unresolved external symbol`:

That's because you didn't define `Fisherman::SetFront` in the cpp file.

Comment: yes you're right. ive ammended that. can you tell me why adding windows.h fixed the issue?

Comment: `<X3DAudio.h>` includes `<windef.h>` which includes `<winnt.h>` which has this line `PCONTEXT ContextRecord;`. This was not defined and by including `#include <Windows.h>` it defined the proper constants to make sure `PCONTEXT` was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Whole code would be helpfull. Did you remember obvious to give namespace to names of functions etc?

```
class A { void foo() { } };
=>
class A { void foo(); }
void A::foo() { ... }
```

etc?

Fastest way would be reverting back to state when it worked, and not moving whole at once, but only one function at a time. Then when problem would occure you could give us that specific code or try to fix it yourself.

Comment: yes i did that too. well i tried that butjust having the "include "fisherman.h" in the cpp file throws this error.

Comment: Remember to include necessary files before fisherman.h. I usally include STL/STD libs then external libs like SDL etc. and then header files, but of course it can differ and still be ok depending on what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that there is just a missed ';', somewhere before this line.

Double-check your code, remember that everything you define in a cpp file has to already be declared in your class definition.

I'd prefer to post a comment, but apparently I'm not allowed.

Anyway, as a simpler way to give us a feel of what you're trying to do, definatley post your code - it does not have to be exactly as you use, but should be a concise piece of generic code, highlighting how you are doing something. ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) If it really is a bug in how you typed it, it would be good to have your exact code, but put it on pastebin and provide a link so that this page doesn't end up with reams of code.

**EDIT:**
winnt.h apparently causes all sorts of problems: [Weird compile error dealing with Winnt.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257134/weird-compile-error-dealing-with-winnt-h)
it is used to provide definitions for winAPI specific headers, as far as I know. One of the solutions proposed on that thread is to get the definitions from a different windows header before including whichever header requires those definitions.

Comment: the thing is, is that the winnt.h file isnt included in the class. but i have posted the code now though =]