# C1189: #error : "No Target Architecture"

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I have the following error when compiling :

> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winnt.h(146): fatal error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture"

Anyway I do not use Windows Kit in my project (or I didn't see it was included). And I tried to change the architecture target in my project with 32, 64 bits, and inherited. Nothing does. Any idea ?

EDIT : list of all the includes. The two first lines are from my project.

```
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :  d:\visual studio 2012\netsdk_poc\mfc_netsdk2\mfc_netsdk2\stdafx.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :   d:\visual studio 2012\netsdk_poc\mfc_netsdk2\mfc_netsdk2\Libs\\netsdk.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stddef.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\sal.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\ConcurrencySal.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vadefs.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\windef.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\winapifamily.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\minwindef.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\specstrings.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :       C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\specstrings_strict.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :        C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\specstrings_undef.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :       C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\driverspecs.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :        c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\sdv_driverspecs.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\ctype.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>  Remarque : inclusion du fichier :       C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\kernelspecs.h
```

Comment: Where are you changing the architecture of the project?

Comment: I have a MFC app so I cannot include windows.h again ;)
fatal error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>

Comment: DoctorLove : Project Properties -> Linker -> Computer Target (I'm translating, in french it is "Ordinateur cible")

Comment: *Linker -> Advanced -> Computer Target

Comment: The linker sets linker settings. The error is coming from compiler preporcessor setting.

Answer (score 8):

The error lines say

```
#if defined(_AMD64_) || defined(_X86_)
#define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD )
#elif defined(_IA64_) || defined(_ARM_)
#define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) (TYPE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) > TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD ) ? \
                              TYPE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) : TYPE_ALIGNMENT( DWORD ))
#elif !defined(RC_INVOKED)
#error "No Target Architecture"
#endif
```

You have #included that header, possibly indirectly by including another header.
You can tell VS2012 to list all the includes it uses by setting "Show Includes" to yes in the `Properties | C/C++ | Advanced` project menu. Then try not including the header that is dragging in `winnt.h` if you don't need it.

`winnt.h` can cause trouble e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257134/weird-compile-error-dealing-with-winnt-h)

**edit**

So, the precompile header includes windef.h which includes the offending header. Try removing the line from the precompiled header.

Comment: I'm gonna see this trick doctorLove. I absolutely wanted to list all the includes !

Comment: OK just to be sure you mean I have to check if winnt is not included twice or more in my project ?

Comment: No not at all - you said you didn't use winnt, so I am trying to help you find out what does so you can remove it

Comment: OK i've searched how to access the pch. I found many sources explaining what the pch is but no how to modify it directly. Could you please explain me this ?

Comment: I have understood it was linked with stdafx and that it was updated during each generation. I've looked in stdafx but there was not winnt.h

Comment: "The precompile header includes windef.h *which includes the offending header*"

Comment: Yes I had understood. But I wouldlike to access the precompile header ;)

Comment: I believe this is a wrong answer and it is not fixing the problem but instead is avoiding it.

Comment: You could be right - feel free to post a better answer if you have one. This will or did show where the prolem was coming from